# iOS Archiving model objects

Tags: ios, model

I'm making an app that keeps track of expenses but in the main screen of the app, I don't need to know about the expenses. However, the user can make transactions from the main screen.

After tapping an icon, The user can see the list of entries for each budget, displayed in a 'UITableView'.

My question: When is the best time to load the array of entries from the file system? I think it might be needless to load it and have a property reference to it from the beginning, but that means I have to unarchive and archive the array every time the user makes a transaction entry.

Also, is there any bad aspects of archiving and unarchiving your custom objects too often?

Comment: performance is irrelevant.  the app will do it in milliseconds. just do it every time - it's the modern way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So usually, unless you have something like a `UITableViewController` that constantly needs to look up the array, it's better not to reference it as a property?

Comment: I would say ... "any bad aspects of archiving and unarchiving your custom objects too often":  answer, "no problem at all: just do that every time."  When you say: "load it and have a property reference to it from the beginning" -- yes, I would do exactly that.  note that there's always annoying details such as, you need a concept "data is still loading! you'll have to wait!" even though that won't happen often.